# Saving tensorflow model after training is finished

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have finished running a big model in tensorflow python. But I have not saved it inside the session. Now that the training is over, I want to save the variables. I am doing the following:

```
saver=tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:  
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "86_model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

This returns : ValueError: No variables to save. According to their website what is missing is initialize_all_variables(). The documentation says little about what exactly that does. The word "initialize" scares me, I do not want to reset all my trained values. Any way to save my model without re-running it?

Comment: `saver.save` saves everything in `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)`. That's a collection that gets updated every time you create a variable with `tf.Variable` or `tf.get_variable`. How did you create your variables?

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarification, I created all my variables in a graph, and trained that network over 100K iterations, got my testing error and the session is closed. I created my variables using tf.Variable(). I want to access those trained variables and save them, but I do not want to use initialize as I assume that will reset my trained variables. I am following Udacity's course as a reference.

Comment: yeah, when you close the session you lose the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like from the tensorflow documentation, the "session" is the thing that holds the information from the trained model. So presumably somewhere you called `sess.run()` to train your model - what you want to do is call `sess.save()` using THAT session, not a new one you create with this saver object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because you are not initializing all of your variables in the saver. This should work

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
      tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
      saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
     -------everything your session does -------------
      checkpoint_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'model.ckpt')
      saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = your_global_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using skflow ? With skflow(now skflow is integrated in tensorflow) you can specify the parameter model_dir on your constructor and that automatically will  save your model while training(it will save checkpoints so if something goes wrong during training, you can restart from last checkpooint).

Comment: There is this problem with skflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597519/adding-regularizer-to-skflow       I ended up using Keras, worked perfectly.