# Adding regularizer to skflow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, skflow

I recently switched form tensorflow to skflow. In tensorflow we would add our lambda*tf.nn.l2_loss(weights) to our loss. Now I have the following code in skflow:

```
def deep_psi(X, y):
    layers = skflow.ops.dnn(X, [5, 10, 20, 10, 5], keep_prob=0.5)
    preds, loss = skflow.models.logistic_regression(layers, y)
    return preds, loss

def exp_decay(global_step):
    return tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=0.01,
                                      global_step=global_step,
                                      decay_steps=1000,
                                      decay_rate=0.005)

deep_cd = skflow.TensorFlowEstimator(model_fn=deep_psi,
                                    n_classes=2,
                                    steps=10000,
                                    batch_size=10,
                                    learning_rate=exp_decay,
                                    verbose=True,)
```

How and where do I add a regularizer here? Illia hints something [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/issues/139) but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still add additional components to loss, you just need to retrieve weights from dnn / logistic_regression and add them to the loss:

```
def regularize_loss(loss, weights, lambda):
    for weight in weights:
        loss = loss + lambda * tf.nn.l2_loss(weight)
    return loss    


def deep_psi(X, y):
    layers = skflow.ops.dnn(X, [5, 10, 20, 10, 5], keep_prob=0.5)
    preds, loss = skflow.models.logistic_regression(layers, y)

    weights = []
    for layer in range(5): # n layers you passed to dnn
        weights.append(tf.get_variable("dnn/layer%d/linear/Matrix" % layer))
        # biases are also available at dnn/layer%d/linear/Bias
    weights.append(tf.get_variable('logistic_regression/weights'))

    return preds, regularize_loss(loss, weights, lambda)
```

```

Note, the path to variables can be [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py#L79).

Also, we want to add regularizer support to all layers with variables (like `dnn`, `conv2d` or `fully_connected`) so may be next week's night build of Tensorflow should have something like this `dnn(.., regularize=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(lambda))`. I'll update this answer when this happens.

Comment: dnn(.., regularize=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(lambda)) will be love though.